# Martin Isaacs's exercise 3.5 (character theory of finite groups)

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I need some help with this exercise:

Suppose $A\subseteq{G}$ is abelian, and $|G:A|$ is a prime power. Show that $G'\lt{G}$

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you mean, $G'\lt A$?

Comment: Nop @GerryMyerson, I already checked the book and the exercise is as it is written here. Apaprently Martin wants the reader to show the commutator sbgp. is a *proper* one...

Comment: If we suppose $G'=G$, then $Lin(G)=Irr(\frac{G}{G'})={1}$, and $G$ would only have one linear character. This would lead us to something?

Comment: @Don, thanks, I completely missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Reduce to a simple group and apply theorem 3.9.

Reduction to simple group:

> Suppose by way of contradiction that $G'=G$. If $G$ is not simple, then $G$ has a proper non-identity normal subgroup $N$. If $AN=G$, then $G/N = AN/N \cong A/A\cap N$ is abelian, so $G=G' \leq N$, contradicting $N$ being proper. Hence $\bar G = G/N$ is a finite group with abelian subgroup $\bar A = AN/N \leq \bar G$, and $[\bar G:\bar A]$ (which divides $[G:A]$) is a prime power. However, $\bar G' = \bar G$, so we have a smaller counterexample. Continuing in this way, we may assume $G$ is simple (lest we find a new $N$).

Final contradiction:

> However, for any non-identity element $a \in A$, $A \leq C_G(a)$ since $A$ is abelian, so $[G:C_G(a)]$ divides $[G:A]$, a prime power. This contradicts theorem 3.9 which says that the only $a \in G$ (for $G$ simple) with $[G:C_G(a)]$ a prime power is $a=1$ with $[G:C_G(a)]=1$. $\square$

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thanks a lot, Jack!

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that $A$ is a normal abelian subgroup of $G$. Then we can use the idea in the above comments,i.e., show that there is a nontrivial degree 1 representation of $G$.

First we have $|G|=\sum_{\chi\in Irr(G)}\chi^2(1)=n_1+\sum_{\chi\in Irr(G),\chi(1)>1}\chi^2(1)$. Ito's theorem gives $\chi(1)\big||G:A|$, which is a prime power. Then the number $n_1$ of linear characters of $G$ is divisible by $p$. So $n_1\neq 1$. Then $G/G'$ is nontrivial.

Comment: that's if $A$ is normal but if it is not then the prove is not complete